# How to display one row of six columns on desktop and two rows of three columns on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a section that contains 6 images. I want to display them in a single row of 6 columns on desktop and then in 2 rows of 3 columns on mobile.

I am able to achieve the desired layout on desktop. But on mobile, the images appear stacked on top of each other in a single column. I want them to appear in 2 rows with 3 columns each.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you have made any CSS yet, then kindly share it with us or just check the answer for a new CSS of the demanded output

Comment: Try reading the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the following is your html then try adding the given CSS for desired outputs -

CSS & HTML-

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.row img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  height: 100px;
}

.col-sm-4:nth-child(1) {
  background: #999;
}

.col-sm-4:nth-child(2) {
  background: #888;
}

.col-sm-4:nth-child(3) {
  background: #777;
}

.col-sm-4:nth-child(4) {
  background: #555;
}

.col-sm-4:nth-child(5) {
  background: #333;
}

.col-sm-4:nth-child(6) {
  background: #111;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-lg-2 {
    float: left;
    width: 16.6%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Kindly resize the browser window to see the results.

Comment: Kindly let me know if you need any sort of help and please accept my answer if you think that I was able to solve your problem.

Comment: This is the wrong solution. The answer is to follow the bootstrap docs and not create unneeded custom code or overwrite bootstrap core code https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: You should not be overriding Bootstrap's grid CSS... he just needs to use the `col-4` class instead of `col-sm-4`

Comment: he haven't mentioned anywhere in his question that he is using bootstrap, he just wants to know, that how can he achieve that, and because of it, I gave him a demonstration of CSS for that ! All what I mean was concept of doing it, but if he already have a bootstrap solution, then of course, the other answer is helpful.

Comment: @Om_16 the question is tagged Bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

Remove the "-sm" from the classname as this targets screens of ≥576px. Bootstrap 4 is mobile first so you just need to use "col-4" for the smallest screen sizes <576px as is explained in the documentation here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```